# What is the difference between using a recursive function in Python and JS?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

Trying to use recursive function in JS, but code isn`t work:

```js
let arr = [6, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]

function sum(ars, i) {
  if (ars.length == i) {
    return 0
  }
  return ars[i] + sum(ars[1])
}
console.log(sum(arr, 0))

// Output: 6
```

But the same code works in python:

```
arr = [2,5,3,1,1,1,1]

def sum(array):
    if array==[]:
        return 0
    return array[0]+sum(array[1:])
    
print (sum(arr))
```

Can anyone explain what is the difference and what am I doing wrong in the JS code?

Comment: What do you think this `array[1:]` does? It is not the same as `ars[1]`

Comment: For one you are sending one parameter `sum(ars[1])` but the function expects two. Furthermore, `ars[1]` is a number not an array so the `.length` call will fail.

Comment: `+ sum(ars[1])` - here you are passing one _item_ out of your array, whereas `+sum(array[1:])` presumably picks _all_ the array items from the second to end?

Comment: Returns the items from index 1 to the end list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sum(ars[1])
```

`ars[1]` means "access the element at index 1". It does *not* get the tail of the array (ie, the sub-array from index 1 to n). Element 1 equals `5`, so this is doing `sum(5)`, which then gets messed up because the code expects an array, not a number.

To get the tail of an array you can use the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method:

```js
let arr = [6, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]

function sum(ars) {
  if (ars.length == 0) {
    return 0
  }
  return ars[0] + sum(ars.slice(1))
}

console.log(sum(arr))
```